# Python removing all \r\n within quotes in CSV file

Tags: python, string, csv, replace

I have a CSV file that has some data in it. I want to replace all the newlines within "" by some character. But the new lines outside of these quotes should stay. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''

    print(argv[0:])
    inputfile = argv[0:]

    file_object = open(argv[0:], "r")
    print(file_object)

    data = file.read(file_object)
    strings = data.split('"')[1::2]

    for string in strings:
        string.replace("\r", "")
        string.replace("\n", "")
        print(string)

    f = open("output.csv", "w")
    for string in strings:
        string = string.replace("\r", "")
        string = string.replace("\n", "")
        f.write(string)

    f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

This does not quite work, since the "" get lost as well as the ,'s.

Expected input:

```
“dssdlkfjsdfj   \r\n ashdiowuqhduwqh \r\n”,
 "3"
```

Expected output:

```
"dssdlkfjsdfj    ashdiowuqhduwqh",
 "3"
```

Comment: This line `data = file.read(file_object)` what is `file`? Did you mean `data = file_object.read()`?

Comment: Please also [provide sample input, sample output along with expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am using python 3.6, not sure if that works the same. But it basically opens the file and reads it as a string.

Comment: The unicode character for your first set of quotation marks is not the standard ASCII quotation mark character. `“ ”` vs `""` This may cause hindrances for your `data.split('"')`.

Comment: Are the \r\n characters literal newlines (i.e. in Python, would be matched with `'\\r\\n'`) or are the newlines *actual newlines* (i.e. there's supposed to be a line break in the text file)?

Comment: Of course, I meant " only.

Comment: Of course, if you provide a "real" cut-n-paste sample of the data instead of `asdfasdfasdf` and mis-typed quotes, we could provide a real solution.  The `csv` module can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real sample would help, but given `in.csv`:

```
"multi
line
data","more data"
"more multi
line data","other data"
```

The following will replace newlines in quotes:

```
import csv

with open('in.csv',newline='') as fin:
    with open('out.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
        r = csv.reader(fin)
        w = csv.writer(fout)
        for row in r:
            row = [col.replace('\r\n','**') for col in row]
            w.writerow(row)
```

out.csv:

```
multi**line**data,more data
more multi**line data,other data
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved in a very easy way. Create an output file, and read the input file for each character. Write each character to the output file, but toggle replace mode by using the ~ operator when a " appears. When in replace mode, replace all \r\n with '' (nothing).